# C# Callback Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, callback, steam

My C# is far rustier than I expected so I was looking for a little help to get my project off the ground. I've tried a number of C# to VB converters but none of them can handle the SteamKit2 example provided in terms of callbacks and all my researching, experimenting with WithEvents and other attempts have failed. I apologize if this is beyond the scope of a normal stackoverflow question but the bottom line is I'm looking for a working VB.net version of the C# SteamKit2 example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using SteamKit2;

//
// Sample 2: The Callback Manager
//
// this sample introduces the callback manager
// the callback manager is a class which can simplify the design of your program
//
// the callback manager's task is to modify the callback loop so that the handling of callbacks
// can be done in your own functions, rather than in-line with the loop
//
// in addition to the manager, your code must create an instance of a Callback<T> class
// this class routes a specific callback type to a function, and is bound only to a specific
// callback manager
//

namespace Sample2_CallbackManager
{
    class Program
    {
        static SteamClient steamClient;
        static CallbackManager manager;

        static SteamUser steamUser;

        static bool isRunning;

        static string user, pass;


        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            if ( args.Length < 2 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Sample2: No username and password specified!" );
                return;
            }

            // save our logon details
            user = args[ 0 ];
            pass = args[ 1 ];

            // create our steamclient instance
            steamClient = new SteamClient();
            // create the callback manager which will route callbacks to function calls
            manager = new CallbackManager( steamClient );

            // get the steamuser handler, which is used for logging on after successfully connecting
            steamUser = steamClient.GetHandler<SteamUser>();

            // register a few callbacks we're interested in
            // these are registered upon creation to a callback manager, which will then route the callbacks
            // to the functions specified
            new Callback<SteamClient.ConnectedCallback>( OnConnected, manager );
            new Callback<SteamClient.DisconnectedCallback>( OnDisconnected, manager );

            new Callback<SteamUser.LoggedOnCallback>( OnLoggedOn, manager );
            new Callback<SteamUser.LoggedOffCallback>( OnLoggedOff, manager );

            isRunning = true;

            Console.WriteLine( "Connecting to Steam..." );

            // initiate the connection
            steamClient.Connect();

            // create our callback handling loop
            while ( isRunning )
            {
                // in order for the callbacks to get routed, they need to be handled by the manager
                manager.RunWaitCallbacks( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ) );
            }
        }

        static void OnConnected( SteamClient.ConnectedCallback callback )
        {
            if ( callback.Result != EResult.OK )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Unable to connect to Steam: {0}", callback.Result );

                isRunning = false;
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "Connected to Steam! Logging in '{0}'...", user );

            steamUser.LogOn( new SteamUser.LogOnDetails
            {
                Username = user,
                Password = pass,
            } );
        }

        static void OnDisconnected( SteamClient.DisconnectedCallback callback )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Disconnected from Steam" );

            isRunning = false;
        }

        static void OnLoggedOn( SteamUser.LoggedOnCallback callback )
        {
            if ( callback.Result != EResult.OK )
            {
                if ( callback.Result == EResult.AccountLogonDenied )
                {
                    // if we recieve AccountLogonDenied or one of it's flavors (AccountLogonDeniedNoMailSent, etc)
                    // then the account we're logging into is SteamGuard protected
                    // see sample 6 for how SteamGuard can be handled

                    Console.WriteLine( "Unable to logon to Steam: This account is SteamGuard protected." );

                    isRunning = false;
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine( "Unable to logon to Steam: {0} / {1}", callback.Result, callback.ExtendedResult );

                isRunning = false;
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "Successfully logged on!" );

            // at this point, we'd be able to perform actions on Steam

            // for this sample we'll just log off
            steamUser.LogOff();
        }

        static void OnLoggedOff( SteamUser.LoggedOffCallback callback )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Logged off of Steam: {0}", callback.Result );
        }
    }
}
```

It's the `new Callback<SteamClient.ConnectedCallback>( OnConnected, manager );` that are my primary stumbling block but for all I know some of the earlier parts like GetHandler didn't translate as well though they passed compilation.

Anyway, any advice (or a complete conversion) would be greatly appreciated!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this for the statements that are giving you trouble:

```
Dim TempConnectedCallback As Callback(Of SteamClient.ConnectedCallback) = New Callback(Of SteamClient.ConnectedCallback)(AddressOf OnConnected, manager)
```

The reason for this is that VB does not allow object instantiations that aren't assigned to anything.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick... now I have a much rougher road to hoe, none of SteamKit2 is documented and their samples are tied to callbacks that aren't grouped and are perhaps not even the best way to implement the features I was planning lol